# Migration Schema vs Seed Table

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-migrate

I want to confirm a bit about Flask Migrate Schema vs Seed Initial Data.

Currently, i am working with Python and Flask Migrate and Flask Restful + Flask Blueprint,

So in my code, what i do currently is:

1. Already defining schema in models

   import datetime
   import uuid
   from app import db
   from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
   from sqlalchemy.event import listen
   from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
   from flask_security.utils import hash_password

   class Award(db.Model):
   **tablename** = 'award'
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String)
   image_url = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
   created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
   updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=True, onupdate=db.func.current_timestamp())

So in **init**.py of app, i define it

```
# from authlib.integrations.flask_client import OAuth
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemySessionUserDatastore
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

# Create package object. 
db = SQLAlchemy()
ma = Marshmallow()
jwt = JWTManager()
api = Api() 
security = Security()

# Initialize the package that needed
def init_app(name, config=None):
    app = Flask(name)
    app.config.from_object(config)
    db.init_app(app)
    ma.init_app(app)
    api.init_app(app)
    CORS(app)
    security.init_app(app)
    

    from .models.award_model import Award
```

So what i need to do is to have a seed data to this data.
But the current issue, i do not know how to define it in correct way.

Is there any sugesstion?

What i think is:

1. Create a bulk insert in model.
2. Create a command line code for seeding (like laravel)

Comment: There is no correct way. You can add a custom command, or add the bulk data in the migration script. Both approaches work, so use the one you like best.

Comment: Hi @Miguel, I am so glad can connect to you. Your course for Flask is the best especially for me that coming from the PHP field. 
Back to topic: 
I think I agree with you, currently do not see any best practice for this one. 
I think I will follow laravel.com pattern :D 
Thanks sir.